# Change the parent lookup kwarg in nested routes using Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular, drf-nested-routers

In this project we use Django, Django REST Framework, DRF Nested Routers and DRF Spectacular.

Let's say that we have the model classes `Category` and `Product`.

We have a nested route:

- `/categories/<category_pk>/products/<pk>/`

In the Swagger UI (generated by DRF Spectacular) it is displayed as:

- `/categories/{category_pk}/products/{id}/`

I want to change the parent lookup keyword argument to be `category_id`, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple, but you have to look at the right place. I was trying to set it in `ProductViewSet` with `parent_lookup_kwargs`, and similarly in the serializers. But that didn't help.

I added `lookup_url_kwarg` in the `CategoryViewSet` and it works like a charm:

```py
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = "id"
```

Otherwise Django REST Framework defaults to "pk". DRF Spectacular changes it to `{id}` in the Swagger UI.
But for the nested routes it can't change the composed name `category_pk`. The `lookup_url_kwarg` set to `"id"` did the trick.